# Java Spring MVC application integrated with SAP ERP

Tags: java, integration, sap-erp, jco

This is not the place but I could not find any place to write.

I am developing a spring mvc app and I need to integrate it to SAP. But I do not have SAP as you guess. I have related JCO libraries but how can I develop codes without having SAP for instance fetching user data, material data vs...

How IT companies develop this kind of appliactions?

What can I do?

Comment: What kind of integration do you want?

Comment: I need to write a interface between SAP and my system then require to fetch especially user list and material list then add these data to my system's database in order to process. Sent request must come from SAP with IDOC and my system will read IDOC and do the fetch jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Same situation here (SAP JCO 2.x). Our workaround: On the target systems every incoming IDOC is exported as xml (Idoc.Document#writeXML). For testing, debugging etc. we implemented a JDom based wrapper (implementing Idoc.Document (JDom document) and Idoc.Segment (for each JDom element)). So we can import the xml and do further processing on this Idoc.Document as usual. Maybe it's only useful for simple cases, but has the additional advantage of a possible reimport in case of failure.